Parsing error: was not found by the project service, but I've ignored these files
My project structure

dist (compiled code by ts)

lib

lib.d.ts
lib.js


index.d.ts
index.js


src (source code)

lib

lib.ts


index.ts


eslint.config.mjs
packages.json
tsconfig.json
yarn.lock

My tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "declaration": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "eslint.config.mjs",
        "dist/**"
    ]
}

My eslint.config.mjs:
// @ts-check

import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import tsParser from '@typescript-eslint/parser'

import { dirname } from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
    
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

export default tseslint.config(
  {
    files: [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    ignores: [
      'dist/**/*.ts',
      'dist/**',
      "**/*.mjs",
      "eslint.config.mjs",
      "**/*.js"
    ],
    rules: {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": "error",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion": "error",
    },
  },
  ...tseslint.configs.strictTypeChecked,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parserOptions: {
        project: "./tsconfig.json",
        projectService: true,
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        projectFolderIgnoreList: [
          "**dist**",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
);

I want tsc to put compiled outputs fo dist folder (I'm new to TypeScript so I don't know if this is the right way to a TS project).
I've ignored files under dist folder but I still got these errors:
/Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/index.d.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: /Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/index.d.ts was not found by the project service. Consider either including it in the tsconfig.json or including it in allowDefaultProject

/Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/index.js
  0:0  error  Parsing error: /Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/index.js was not found by the project service. Consider either including it in the tsconfig.json or including it in allowDefaultProject

/Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/lib/lib.d.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: /Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/lib/lib.d.ts was not found by the project service. Consider either including it in the tsconfig.json or including it in allowDefaultProject

/Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/lib/lib.js
  0:0  error  Parsing error: /Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/dist/src/lib/lib.js was not found by the project service. Consider either including it in the tsconfig.json or including it in allowDefaultProject

/Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/eslint.config.mjs
  0:0  error  Parsing error: /Users/kainzhong/VSCode/eslintTmp/eslint.config.mjs was not found by the project service. Consider either including it in the tsconfig.json or including it in allowDefaultProject

Haven't I already ignored these files? Why does eslint still complain about them?

Btw, you don't need to specify both tseslint.configs.strictTypeChecked and tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked. strictTypeCheckedis a superset ofrecommendedTypeChecked`.

You also don't need to specify both parserOptions.project and parserOptions.projectService. projectService takes precedence. You can just specify that.

This config doesn't actually ignore those files - that's the issue. ignores has two ways of behaving:

When in a config block with files, it stops that specific config block from affecting those ignored files
When in their own config block without files, it tells ESLint to ignore those files

Move the ignores to their own block at the start:
export default tseslint.config(
  {
    ignores: [
      'dist/**/*.ts',
      'dist/**',
      "**/*.mjs",
      "eslint.config.mjs",
      "**/*.js"
    ],
  },
  {
    files: [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
  // ...

From https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#excluding-files-with-ignores.

OMG thank you that works like a charm!

I had to read so much to find this simple answer. Thank you
